# How to add shipment numbers to sales_order_grid column?

Tags: magento2, order-grid

So, question is: how can i correctly add column with shipment numbers from
[image]

to sales order grid table?
Currently i made it with plugin but there're several issues:

got an error at order's shipment tab:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_id' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table` WHERE (`order_id` = '5') AND (`order_id` = '5') AND (`order_id` = '5')
```

got just 12 orders instead of ~100

plugin:

```
public function __construct(MessageManager $messageManager,
    SalesOrderGridCollection $collection
) {

    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    $this->collection = $collection;
}

public function aroundGetReport(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $requestName
) {
    $result = $proceed($requestName);
    if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
        if ($result instanceof $this->collection
        ) {
            $select = $this->collection->getSelect();

            $select->joinRight(
            ['sst' => 'sales_shipment_track'], "main_table.entity_id = sst.order_id"); 

            $select->joinRight(
                                'sales_shipment_track',
                                'main_table.entity_id = sales_shipment_track.order_id',
                                array(
                                    'numbers'  => new \Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_shipment_track`.track_number SEPARATOR ",")')
                                )
                            );

            $select->group('main_table.entity_id');

        }

    }

    return $this->collection;
}
```

}

**di.xml**:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
<plugin name="sales_order_additional_columns" type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\AddColumnsSalesOrderGridCollection" sortOrder="100" disabled="false" />
```

and **sales_order_grid.xml**:

```
<column name="track_number">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Track numbers</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">252</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">right</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>

            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Thanks in advance.